# JSQMessages text view only

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a comment view like instagram and would like to have a text with + containerView with the containerView increasing in size as my text view grwos, is it possible to just use JSQMessages with the text view only without the chat?

P/S: I mention JSQMessages is because the app will later require chat, so was thinking if I can use back the same framework for this smaller matter.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, using only the input bar of jsqmessages. How did you ended up implementing this @Happiehappie?

Answer (score 0):

Ya just hide the input bar and there you go you have dynamic text bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.inputToolbar?.hidden = true;
}
```